# Is it possible to compress the edges in dendrograms?

Tags: r, dendrogram

I am trying to visualise a dendrogram in R but the labels get cropped since the tree edges take the majority of the real estate.

Here's a minimal example:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
clusDendro <- as.dendrogram(hc)
clusDendro <- dendrapply(clusDendro, colLab)
plot(clusDendro, horiz = T)
```

[image]

Is there a way to compress the length of the edges?

Comment: @Cath The thing is I dont want to limit (as in cut) the x-axis, I want to it take less space. Also, I added a minimal example as suggested

Comment: @Cath thanks for the tip, however unless my understanding of the R plotting functions is flawed that only makes the resultant plot bigger, so that the labels fit. While it solves the problem of trimmed labels, it does not solve the issue of edges taking so much space.

Comment: It is my understanding that the lengths of each edge has a mathematical/statistical meaning. The longer the edge, the larger the difference, or the more effective the clustering. That said, it looks like you might be able to do some adjustments with the dendrogram object. See `dendrogram`. The edge.root argument looks promising.